# Insert the username, of person opening a file, into a hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, href

The following VBA enters the below path as a hyperlink in an automated email when a spreadsheet is completed. This works just for me:

```
<A HREF=""C:\Users\james.jordan\Spiral Ltd\Eng Sales
```

The spreadsheet and directory (SharePoint) is available for numerous people to access and complete.

Is there a way for VBA to identify the user amending the spreadsheet to enter their username in the path instead of mine?

Answer (score 0):

So the following VBA will enter the current user into a hyperlink:

```
“<A HREF=“”C:\users” & (environ$(“username”)) & “\Spiral ltd.....
```